# Access child type's properties from Angular template

Tags: angular, types, angular2-template

I suspect this question has already been answered, but all answers I can find are about child components, not child types.

I have two interfaces. (edit to clarify: I do have more items that inherit from Item, and any of these child types of `Item` can be in the list. Otherwise I could make a list of `MagicItem`s, but that does not work in my case)

```
export interface Item {
   name: string;
   value: string;
}

export interface MagicItem extends Item {
   abilities: string[];
}
```

I have a list of `Item`s in my component, with a few `MagicItem`s in that same list. Can I access `abilities` from the template? If I try, I get the warning that `'abilities' does not exist on type 'Item'`.

I have tried using `*ngIf="typeof(item) === 'MagicItem'"` and `(item as MagicItem).abilities` but I cannot seem to get that working in the template. The latter does work in the typescript code.

Comment: how about `*ngIf="item?.abilities"`?

Comment: the array should have the type `MagicItem[]` it is applicable for both cases. not vice versa

Comment: `*ngIf="item?.abilities"` doesn't work, unfortunately. I fear it is as shutsman says. That would mean I have to make a separate list for each type that derives from `Item`, which I would like to avoid if possible.